# jquery can not set this to current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i console.log the `form` variable, it always set to `window` even though it's in the `.ajax-form` class selector, which contains 3 forms. how can i make `$(this)` to be the form? here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(() => {
  // reloading comment
  $('.ajax-form').each(() => {
    const form = $(this);
    form.submit((event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log(form);
      $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: form.serialize(),
      }).done((data) => {
        console.log(data);
          // location.reload();
      }).fail((data) => {
        const errors = data;
        console.log(errors);
        Object.entries(errors).forEach((error) => {
          const label = form.find(`label[for='${error}']`);
          label.text(error[1][0]);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: can you share some HTML explaining roughly how the forms look inside the `.ajax-form` class element

Comment: @caramba how does that related to my question?

Comment: I would have tried to run your code which depends on HTML, then maybe I could have explained what, why, where. The HTML in my opinion is more important to reproduce your problem then the ajax request part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the arrow function has no its own this context, but only execution context, i.e. window object in this example.

You can pass the element to function:

```
$('.ajax-form').each((_i, elem) => {
  const form = $(elem);
})
```

or function keyword:

```
$('.ajax-form').each(function(){
  const form = $(this);
})
```

Comment: interesting. i just realize it might has something to do with es6 syntax. do you mind telling me what do you mean by "has no its own this context, but only execution context"?  @Jeremy Fan

Comment: @MarshallX maybe [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this) could help. (sorry about my english)